# Concept of vptr and vtable in C++

Tags: c++, default-constructor, vtable, vptr

Why only default constructor only able to create vptr(Virtual Table Pointer) and vtable(Virtual Table)? Why parameter constructor not able to

Comment: *"Why only default constructor only able to create vptr(Virtual Table Pointer) and vtable(Virtual Table)?"* Where did you get that idea? That does not make any sense.

Comment: constructors don't make virtual anythings.   having a virtual function in a type makes the type polymorphic, but that's a compile-time thing and has nothing to do with what constructors do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, vtables and vptrs are not specified by the C++ language standard.

They're an implementation detail, although as far as I know all extant C++ implementation use that technique to implement virtual function dispatch.

With such an implementation, *all* constructors for a class with virtual member functions, necessarily establish the object's vptr. Things wouldn't work without it. So …

> **”** Why parameter constructor not able to

… is simply an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Also, *no* constructor creates any vtables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the implementation uses vtables (a  pretty common implementation choice, as noted by "Cheers and hth - Alf"), the creation/population of vtables and invoking constructors are distinct operations.

However, all instances of a given (non-abstract) class will - once constructed fully - have the same set of vtables   (a class that inherits from multiple bases may have more than one vtable).    There will certainly not be a different vtable depending on how the object is constructed (e.g. what parameters are passed to constructors, which constructor is invoked, etc).